# How to use Jbuttons with Combo boxes inside a switch statement in Java

Tags: java

This is my first time posting, please be kind and know that I'll remember to fix any suggestions!

I am trying to create a program that draws shapes. I need my program to show only one selection, circle, square, or triangle at a time. When I click the "Draw a.. " option, it should draw only the corresponding shape with the height or radius labeled on the sides. The shapes are a fixed size but the labels need to reflect what the user enters.

However, I'm using a switch statement to toggle between them. My switch is showing everything at once! How do I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{ 


            JTextField num1;
            JTextField num2;
            JTextField num3;
            JTextField num4;
            JLabel equals;
            JTextField answer;
            JLabel labelTxt;
            JComboBox shapeList;
            JButton drawAThing;
            JLabel radiusLabel;
            JLabel base;
            JLabel lengthLabel;
            JLabel height;
            JButton drawACircle;
            JButton drawASquare;
            JButton drawATriangle;

    MainPanel(){

        String [] shapes = {"circle", "square", "triangle"};
        shapeList = new JComboBox(shapes);
        shapeList.setSelectedIndex(2);
        shapeList.addActionListener(this); 
        add(shapeList); 


    }

            @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        Object a = e.getSource();

        if (o == shapeList){
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            String msg = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();


            switch(msg){
            case "circle": 
                radiusLabel = new JLabel();
                radiusLabel.setText("Radius: ");
                add(radiusLabel);

                num1 = new JTextField(12);
                add(num1);


                drawACircle = new JButton("Draw a circle ");
                drawACircle.addActionListener(this);
                add(drawACircle);

                if (a == drawACircle){

                    drawACircleThing();
                    remove(drawACircle);

                    this.revalidate();
                    this.repaint();
                    }



                break;

            case "square":
                    lengthLabel = new JLabel();
                    lengthLabel.setText("Side Length: ");
                    add(lengthLabel);

                    num2 = new JTextField(12);
                    add(num2);


                    drawASquare = new JButton("Draw a square ");
                    drawASquare.addActionListener(this);
                    add(drawASquare);

                    if (a == drawASquare){

                    drawASquareThing();
                    remove(drawASquare);

                    this.revalidate();
                    this.repaint();
                    }

               break;

            case "triangle":
                    base = new JLabel();
                    base.setText("Base: ");
                    add(base);

                    num3 = new JTextField(12);
                    add(num3);

                    height = new JLabel();
                    base.setText("height: ");
                    add(height);

                    num4 = new JTextField(12);
                    add(num4);


                    drawATriangle = new JButton("Draw a triangle ");
                    drawATriangle.addActionListener(this);
                    add(drawATriangle);

                    if (a == drawATriangle){

                        drawATriangleThing();

                    remove(drawATriangle);

                    this.revalidate();
                    this.repaint();

                    }

                    break;


                 default:
                    break;

        }
    }
    }

            @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE ); 
    g.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
    g.fillOval(100,100,200,200);

}
private void drawASquareThing()
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(150,100,330,200);    
    g.drawString("My square", 50, 10); 

}
private void drawATriangleThing()
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillRect(150,100,330,200);    
        g.drawString("My Triangle", 50, 10); 

}

public void drawACircleThing()
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

    int [] xPoints = {50, 50, 100};
    int [] yPoints = {50, 100, 100};

    g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);
    g.fillPolygon(yPoints, xPoints, 3);

}


}
```

My new code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{ 


            JTextField num1;
            JTextField num2;
            JTextField num3;
            JTextField num4;

            JTextField answer;
            JLabel labelTxt;
            JComboBox shapeList;
            JButton drawAThing;
            JLabel radiusLabel;
            JLabel base;
            JLabel lengthLabel;
            JLabel height;
            JButton drawACircle;
            JButton drawASquare;
            JButton drawATriangle;

    MainPanel(){

        String [] shapes = {"circle", "square", "triangle"};
        shapeList = new JComboBox(shapes);
        shapeList.setSelectedIndex(2);
        shapeList.addActionListener(this); 
        add(shapeList); 

    setVisible(true);


    }

            @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        Object a = e.getSource();

        if (o == shapeList){
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            String message = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();


            switch(message){
            case "circle": 

                radiusLabel = new JLabel();
                radiusLabel.setText("Radius: ");
                add(radiusLabel);

                num1 = new JTextField(12);
                add(num1);
                int radiusSize = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText());
                this.revalidate();
                drawACircle = new JButton("Draw a circle ");
                drawACircle.addActionListener(this);
                add(drawACircle);

                if (a == drawACircle){

                    drawACircleThing(radiusSize);

                    }

                    this.repaint();

                break;

            case "square":

                    lengthLabel = new JLabel();
                    lengthLabel.setText("Side Length: ");
                    add(lengthLabel);

                    num2 = new JTextField(12);
                    add(num2);
                    int lengthSize = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText());
                    this.revalidate();
                    drawASquare = new JButton("Draw a square ");
                    drawASquare.addActionListener(this);
                    add(drawASquare);


                    if (a == drawASquare){

                    drawASquareThing(lengthSize);


                    }

                    this.repaint();

               break;

            case "triangle":

                    base = new JLabel();
                    base.setText("Base: ");
                    add(base);


                    num3 = new JTextField(12);
                    add(num3);
                    int baseSize = Integer.parseInt(num3.getText());

                    height = new JLabel();
                    base.setText("height: ");
                    add(height);

                    num4 = new JTextField(12);
                    add(num4);
                    int heightSize = Integer.parseInt(num4.getText());
                    this.revalidate();
                    drawATriangle = new JButton("Draw a triangle ");
                    drawATriangle.addActionListener(this);
                    add(drawATriangle);

                    if (a == drawATriangle){

                        drawATriangleThing(baseSize, heightSize);

                    }

                    this.repaint();

                   break;

                 default:
                    break;

        }
    }
 }

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) //The last thing that is called and passed by java run time environment of Graphics g. It let’s us draw on the screen.
{
g.setColor(Color.BLUE ); // NEED an import. Don’t need to know all the colors.
g.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
g.fillOval(100,100,200,200);

}
private void drawASquareThing(int lengthSize)
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
        g.drawRect(lengthSize, 45, 25, 35);
        g.drawString("My Square", 30, 23);        
}
private void drawATriangleThing(int baseSize, int heightSize)
{

    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(60,79,809,400); 
        g.drawRect(baseSize, baseSize, heightSize, heightSize);
        g.drawString("My Triangle", baseSize, heightSize); 

}

public void drawACircleThing(int radiusSize)
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

    int [] xPoints = {50, 50, 100};
    int [] yPoints = {50, 100, 100};

    g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, radiusSize);
    g.fillPolygon(yPoints, xPoints, 3);

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do more swing tutorials on doing custom painting. But basically, you should be doing everything in your paintComponent method, and in your other methods you should be setting up the variables / parameters used in paintComponent. For instance (using your code)

```
            @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE ); 
    if (fillSquareFlag) g.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
    if (fillCircleFlag) g.fillOval(100,100,200,200);

}
```

With that, you can set up your button Actions for your Buttons like

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  fillSquareFlag = !fillSquareFlag;
  repaint();
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the fillSquareFlag but what is it? Is it a Boolean operator? Would I add it underneath drawATriangleThing(baseSize, heightSize); everytime I try to call the drawAMethod?